# How to avoid the image to be 'tinted' in an option of UIDocumentMenuViewController

Tags: ios, menuitem, viewcontroller

In my app I have a button to import a photo. I want to offer a choice to pickup the photo from multiple sources, including the App Photos. So, I use **UIDocumentMenuViewController** and add a menu item for the App Photos. The "icon-photos" is that multicolour kind of flower.

```
[importMenu addOptionWithTitle: @"Photos"
                         image: [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-photos"]
                         order: UIDocumentMenuOrderLast handler:^
    {
        NSLog(@">>> Photos");
    }];
```

I tried to use a JPG, a PNG, I tried to add

```
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-photos"] 
       imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]
```

but I always have the menu image tinted in blue! How can I keep the original colors?

### [image]

Comment: Did you find any solution???